# What is the definition of the word Christianity in relation to this site?

Tags: discussion

Could you please define the word that bears the title of this site, Christianity, in terms accepted by this site?

I think this question may have an answer in the provided link below, but because of the nature of the post and it's title the answer may be hard to find.  Creating a clearly stated question with a clear answer minus other unrelated text would be helpful to others coming to this site and also as a reference to refer to in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Christianity.SE vs. Survivor](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor)

Comment: @curiousdannii I would suggest it does not answer my question because it simply provides one example of what this site is not.  It does not define what the term Christian affirmatively means at this site.  I would like a positive affirmation of what the word 'Christianity' means as it relates to how this site functions.

Comment: On this site "Christianity" is what anyone who self-identifies as "Christian" wants it to mean.

Comment: @curiousdannii I would like to know if that is the true answer, because I have a follow up, which I'll post in a new question.

Comment: The word 'Christian' was first used in Antioch in about 33 A.D. That is important in the etymology of the word. But as we all know, there is an _etymological fallacy_ that supposes a word used today still has the same meaning as it used to have. Yet, it is still possible to revert back to the original meaning _if - and only if - one chooses to do so and if one can gain the agreement of others in doing so_.  Else, the corruption of the word continues, unabated.

Answer (score 1):

On this site the term [Christianity means anything that a self-identified Christian believes it means](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor).

This is different than what you would find in a dictionary.  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Christianity) for instance has these three definitions.

1: the religion derived from Jesus Christ, based on the Bible as sacred scripture, and professed by Eastern, Roman Catholic, and Protestant bodies
2 : conformity to the Christian religion
3 : the practice of Christianity

Answer (score 0):

Christianity = 
 Christian 
 heretics
 reading
 into
 scripture
 things
 Iesus
 ain't
 never
 intended
 to
 yammer

It's Latin, that's why Jesus is spelt with an I

Answer (score 0):

> *And when he (Barnabus) had found him (Saul of Tarsus), he brought him unto Antioch. And it came to pass, that a whole year they assembled themselves with the church, and taught much people.*
>
> ***And the disciples were called Christians first in Antioch***. Acts 11:26.

Initially, in Antioch, there was a company of people taught by Barnabus and Saul.

They received certain teaching, which they all believed, and they all conformed to certain behaviour, such that other people, round about them, saw a distinction in this specific gathering and called them 'Christ-ian'.

They believed in Christ and they followed Christ *as Christ was represented to them by certain leaders.*

Many now self-identify themselves as 'Christ-ian' but they have not received the teaching that Saul (now known as Paul) expressed in his writings. They have a bible, but they do not actually **receive** what is written therein.

Paul himself, in his writings, predicted this would happen. It was already evident within his own lifetime.

---

The 'Christianity' site on Stack Exchange invites questions regarding all of that which identifies itself as 'Christian' and the site acknowledges the diversity of what now exists.

It remains to the individual to receive what they are led to receive and to reject what they are led to reject.

The secret is in the 'leading'.

Jesus said '*My sheep hear my voice and they follow me*'. Some hear that voice and follow in the footsteps of the true flock. Some hear another voice (much as Eve heard a voice when she was in the garden of Eden) and they are led astray.

As Jesus remarked himself, it is not a matter of 'Lo, here !' or 'Lo, there !' (externally to oneself) but :

> *Behold, the kingdom of God is within you* [Luke 17:21, KJV]

. . .  or, conversely, it is not.

*So, many will self-identify, but few are chosen.* [cf Matthew 22:14, KJV]