Hiring mercenaries in the comments
This question declares that specific members of this community "are accursed". This is not borderline behavior, it is abusive and clearly runs afoul of our code of conduct. I express my hope that the mods will address the matter.
This Meta post, however, is not about that question, but its comments. I am seeking the community's wisdom in how to respond to a more experienced user, who used the comments to encourage the question. This experienced user has left such comments many, many times, encouraging those who write argumentative/inappropriate posts. I'll call this behavior "hiring mercenaries in the comments." (i.e. rather than breaking the rules personally, compensating/encouraging someone else to do so). I can provide a list of examples of using the comments to motivate bad behavior, if that is helpful. For the moment, I'll share just one recent example of hiring mercenaries in the comments - see the comments here. (Appropriately, that entire post was deleted because it responded from the wrong perspective).
If someone writes a poor question (e.g. cloaks an argument as a question, uses the site as a platform to preach, proclaims anathemas, duplicates a prior question in order to solicit additional negativity for a disfavored outgroup, etc.), or a poor answer (e.g. doesn't respond to the question that was asked, blatantly misrepresents a source, etc.):

Is writing a comment to the effect of I agree for XYZ reasons, upvoted +1 productive?
Should our most experienced users model this kind of behavior or something different?

I mean...if I can write posts that violate the code of conduct, net a few positive points, and members of the community openly support/encourage the behavior...should we all just use the site in this way? I get that brand-new users may need some time to figure out how the site works, but should we not expect more from those who've been around for a while?
--
What I'm not asking
Previous, related Meta posts have produced responses suggesting that the denominations most frequently critiqued on this site (Jehovah's Witnesses, The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints), just don't like people poking holes in their beliefs, or that they think this site should protect users from valid and academic inquiry, or that they're uncomfortable with the idea that one's own faith will be tried and tested here. Such responses are very common, they are patronizing, and they entirely miss the point.
All of the regular users on this site from the aforementioned denominations regularly and without difficulty respond to probing, challenging questions about their faith. Sometimes we find "gotcha" questions comically weak, or are tempted to roll our eyes when thoroughly debunked conspiracy theories are breathlessly presented as the pinnacle of reason. Speaking for myself, I actually like to see good, challenging, genuine questions posted here because it provides an opportunity to clearly respond to them (I've asked a few myself for just that reason). I joined the Stack Exchange community because it appeared to be a reasonably rigorous academic site that makes a lot of useful content widely available.
What is exasperating is to see petty political fights sully any attempt at academic rigor. And then to see the community energetically jump in to support the behavior. If we're more interested in "scoring points" in the 1900 year long shouting match, and casting others' views in the worst light possible (no matter if we have to run afoul of that pesky 9th commandment in doing so)...then we're on the wrong website.
I think challenging questions are fine. I'll tip my hat to user Mark who has modeled what good, challenging questions look like more clearly than anyone I've ever seen. I'll echo two statements made by site moderators that are relevant to discerning a challenging question that is useful versus a challenging question that is not:

If your goal in writing an answer or a question is to "make a point," then sadly, you've missed the point of this site!


The expectation on this site is that if you get an answer, you don't argue with it.

--
I'm not asking the community to stop asking probing questions. I'm asking how we respond to behavior that handicaps our ability to be the site described here.
How should we address "hiring mercenaries in the comments?"

My post deliberately did not name the user I'm asking about -- it seemed like fair play not to drop any names. This allows the user to choose (if so desired) to delete the comments in question and then they would not be personally identifiable to those who were not involved.

The links you have provided to one question for LDS and another for JW's make it clear to whom you refer. Might I suggest you modify your question and remove the bit about "hiring mercenaries in the comments"? There is no such thing on Christianity Stack.

What i find most discouraging is providing a thoughtful answer to a question scoped at JWs with citations from official sources, only to receive negative comments from the OP and others stating why the answer is wrong according to their non jw pov. And rarely get a upvote and almost never a green check mark.   Therefore I no longer give thoughtful answers.  I just pop in a link in comments or copy paste something for an answer

It's got to be remembered that some positions, LDS for example, assert that 1800 years of Christendom has gone sideways.  Others assert the opposite.  It's not always overt and I don't think offense is the intent but it's there because of the nature of truth and it goes in all directions from all sources.  We are in a room full of elbows.

I just want to say for the record, that I read many posts on Catholicism or on the early church by several high ranking LDS members (high ranking C.SE-score-wise) and I have been pleasantly surprised to find the posts to be objective and fact-based and that I rarely (maybe never) find posts on other mainstream groups by those members to have polemical intention (or worse).  I think C.SE should be likened to a diplomacy table giving each major group the opportunity to present theological truths as each group sees them, rather than debating which one is the Truth, not that there is no Truth.

I don't know if I'd say mercenary, but maybe riling the crowd/mob/supporters. Too often I feel like users use this site like survivor to vote for opinions they support instead of well asked/answered posts, even when they disagree with the contents. related: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/22319


a more experienced user, who used the comments to encourage the question. This experienced user has left such comments many, many times, encouraging those who write argumentative/inappropriate posts.

Of course this is still in regards to the original question itself.  The fact of saying "I agree. +1", or "Great question! Upvoted!", etc.,  is certainly nothing but an encouragement and surely the only folks who really take issue with such comments are those who take issue with the question.  I would be surprised to find any long time participant on this site who has never given such encouragement to a question or an answer.
Of course we will always encounter questions, answers, and comments that ruffle our feathers.  Truth statements may be disallowed but we each believe in and cling to some 'truths' with the necessary result that others are excluded.  We should all approach one another with this firmly in mind:  Truths statements drive our participation here but they do so from the back seat, from the shadows.
The question referenced at the beginning of this question is a case in point.  (I will use site names for ease and editing is welcome if the names should come off).  Mr. Bond believes that the Gospel, as he understands it, is recorded in the Bible in a forever completed form, i.e. there is no need of/will be no doctrinal additions or corrections.  Hold To The Rod believes that the Gospel, as contained in the Bible, has been corrupted in some areas and that another testament has been given which restores it back to what it once was and should be in content.
The question references Galatians 1:8, a text that both parties hold within their respective canons, which says, "But even though we, or an angel from heaven should preach to you another gospel contrary to that which we have preached to you, let him be accursed.".  Both parties consider that the gospel Paul is referring to is the true gospel which they believe to the natural exclusion of the other.  Both parties could legitimately claim that the anathema of this verse applies to the other party.  Support for either position doesn't have to be born out of a mercenary spirit when it is already born by the distinction between the two gospels and the nature of truth.
If Hold To The Rod's assertion that 'Paul's gospel' of Galatians 1 refers to the same one that is currently being restored from corruption by another testament is actually true then, according to Galatians Mr. Bond is anathema so long as he clings to the corrupted gospel because it is another gospel.
If Mr. Bond's assertion that ''Paul's gospel' of Galatians 1 has never seen corruption and refers to the same one that is currently understood as having been preserved and preached since the beginning is actually true then, according to Galatians 1, Hold To The Rod is anathema so long as he clings to the restored gospel because it is another gospel.
These two 'gospels' exclude each other with the only other option being that these two are false and another is true.  The severity of the exclusion can be pointed out, agreed with, and up-voted as fact using a shared text without any assumed mercenary intent provided that it is remembered, at the forefront, that there are truth statements lurking behind every single question, answer, and comment.  Moreover, there are truth statements we apply to our every reading of same.  We aren't supposed to talk about them and we certainly cannot employ them but they are large and in charge.
Whatever degree of conviction is held as to the truth of a particular 'gospel' that is the degree to which any other 'gospel' is excluded.  This site tends to attract folks who are very deeply convinced that the 'gospel' they cling to is the true gospel.  Of course we should take part here with a demeanor of unfeigned respect but still; the wider the disparity, the thornier the middle ground.  Let the thin-skinned skin beware.
For instance, I am well aware that I am under anathema, according to the Roman Catholic Church, for some of what I am sure is truth.  I am not offended when this is pointed out and I rarely think that offense is intended.
The gospel invites everyone but it also excludes all else and we all volunteer to interact with some folks whom we are certain are dead wrong to one degree or another.  Let's all pony up and admit that.  I contend that when we forget this, when we forget how very fundamentally 'truths' are driving all of us, we may either become antagonistic or offended or be perceived as such.  I suspect that very, very few of us are aiming for mercenary ends but that is for each heart to determine for itself.
It is not easy to participate here as a representative of Christ with love, joy, peace, forbearance, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, gentleness and self-control.  I believe most are trying and none of us have it down cold.
Good question. Up-voted. +1 :)

Good answer - especially the closing paragraph.  Up-voted +1  :-)

I edited 'He' to 'he' in confidence that Mr Bond would agree! Your plain-speaking answer would make you welcome in Yorkshire, where they like to call a spade a spade!

Thanks for the balanced approach, and for the touch of humor at the end =). I see a meaningful difference between you are accursed and the statement your are accursed according to X denomination. I do not claim to have the authority to declare anyone accursed, regardless of how wrong I may think they are on important issues.

I think we need to encourage formulating questions to controversial topics in a neutral tone. Controversial questions of course can and should be asked, but the intent should be always to learn instead of changing the views of others, or simply embarassing them. There is no issue with asking hard questions as long as one is actually interested in an answer.
I think I did a good job on these questions that could have been just as easily formulated confrontational. But weren't because I try my best to hit the neutral tone I want questions and answers here to have. And I think I got rewarded with some good and honest answers.
What role does the Holy Ghost fill that the Father can't?
When did the idea of a scriptural "canon" originate?
History of creatio ex nihilo
Did Swedenborg see himself as a prophet?
Obviously not all my questions are, or can be, great but the rules of thumb I try to follow, and would encourage others to follow, are as follows:

keep out your own opinion as much as possible
keep it short. The longer the question, the higher the chances you will mess up somewhere
be respectful of other beliefs and historical figures

If you want to "poke holes in others beliefs", don't ask the question. If you want to fill the holes in your understanding, go ahead and ask. The same question can be good or bad, depending on how it is asked.
It's natural that there is disagreement regarding What Is The Truth, but there does not need to be disagreement regarding what good questions and answers are.

As someone who finds that the obvious often evades me (but if it's obscure, then I might notice), let me just make three points that might seem obscure to many others.
First, the OP consistently posts high quality questions and provides in-depth answers - which is obvious to everyone - but a little detail in one of his comments here claimed that he upholds fair play by not naming users here, which is why he didn't name the user he's asking about. Yet in the main bulk of his question he says, "I'll tip my hat to user Mark who has modeled what good, challenging questions look like more clearly than anyone I've ever seen." An energetic supportive comment of a user one agrees with. And there's nothing wrong with that, just so long as it's acknowledged that "What's sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander." In other words, equally, there's nothing wrong with making comments to criticize a user who is not posting good questions or relevant answers. Just so long as that is done in a civil manner, with no name-calling or innuendos.
Second point - the Meta question referred to, concluded that "Our differences are more than divisions between us, they are boundaries that define us. I think there are more boundaries than is necessary, but the only hope we have of crossing them is to identify and respect them."
Sometimes one group takes as offensive a question that pushes for an answer that defines a core aspect of that group, which sets it apart from other groups. Simply put, the question is trying to identify one group's boundaries that ought to set it apart from other groups so that we all know where we stand, and whether to remain where we stand, or cross over and join them. "Now't wrong wi' that, lad!" as they might say in Yorkshire (where they like to call a spade a spade.)
But if any question goes beyond the task of trying to get a group to be up-front about its defining core beliefs, the Moderators can remove it. If any answer goes beyond the task of explaining why, or whether, a belief asked about separates that group from other groups' beliefs, it too can be removed by them. Yes, sometimes that happens, so I suggest that the Moderators step in to prevent any escalation, perhaps by vetting each question before they allow it to be posted. That would cause a time-delay. No bad thing if it helps prevent inflammatory questions or comments.
Third point - because of all the hoo-ha and infuriated responses generated by many comments, why not remove the "Comments" facility? Keep the "Chat" facility for those who wish to debate issues and details, but let those of us who just want to engage with questions and answers be left in peace to simply do that, and no more? If the Moderators think it worth while, why not do a trial run (only allowing comments to help new users who need guidance) and after, say, six months, evaluate whether the quality of questions and answers has improved? Just let the questions and answers speak for themselves. Be done with Comments!
Conclusion and Answer to the Question - To accuse some of being hired mercenaries, to comment against a group, perhaps also by commenting favourably to others not in that group, raises this question: Why make that accusation? Do the group members want to suppress question that might expose one of their core beliefs to the general public that would show why their group has to remain distinct, religiously, from other groups? Is today's trend, of merging disparate groups ecumenically, the goal of some who want to close down questions that would show why it might be unwise (from a biblically Christian stance) to cross over to join that other group? Just wondering, and asking (nicely).

I'll second your third point, I'm pretty sick of moving to chatrooms, it's more like a recycle bin.  I wish they'd let us move to a particular chatroom rather than a new one.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266693/could-mods-have-add-comments-to-chat-to-supplement-move-comments-to-chat/400411#400411 They should implement that feature in Monica's honor.

@PeterTurner  What an excellent link! And your recent answer is spot on.

Thanks for the kind words and the sharp eye. I'm a fan of the maxim praise openly and rebuke discretely. Of course, one can only be so discrete on a public website; I attempted to strike a reasonable balance. And I'll certainly grant that I don't always get the balance in exactly the right spot. Either way, I'm always happy to praise someone openly.

Re your final question, thanks for asking (nicely)! =) I added some clarification to the OP. I don't see that users on the site seek to suppress/hide their core beliefs from the public. I do think we all want to see our beliefs presented in a reasonably honest light. From the feedback of various users I see 2 categories of posts people tend to want to close: a) posts that severely misrepresent their beliefs & b) posts that ask about X's beliefs for the purpose of starting an argument that X's beliefs are wrong.

If someone were joining my faith (not the purpose of this site), I'd want them to do so with eyes wide open. Since my church has more than 72k missionaries in 150 countries inviting people to learn about it, and BYU is actively working to publish every document Joseph Smith ever wrote, I'd say that counts as inviting the public eye!

@HoldToTheRod  Your comments noted, with thanks. I would say that readers on here are intelligent enough to weigh up questions, and differing answers, to judge for themselves if bad motives or information is evidenced. But if so, comments should not be used to stir things up. Answers provide an outlet for that, and edits can be added. My own experience over 50 years with the use (and abuse) of religious publications is such that I do sometimes detect raw nerves being touched when certain things are raised that some would wish to be archived (and this applies in all denominations.)

I dislike the accusation Sometimes one group takes as offensive a question that pushes for an answer that defines a core aspect of that group, which sets it apart from other groups. From my perspective when there are lots of comments, they generally point out how it has already been asked/answered. Any clear examples of this?

@depperm  That was an observation, not an accusation. Nor is it confined to this site. I've been on other sites and found this happens a lot. It's also part of my personal interactions with people from many religious groups over 50 years. To ask some questions is to almost guarantee upset, if not offense, but I always try to ask nicely. There's no point giving links for examples of this here, as that will only create more defensive or offensive comments; the very thing the OP and I object to. Why don't you put your points in an answer of your own here?

@Anne I was commenting on your answer. I kind of agree with OP, would use different terminology, but I see where they are coming from. I've asked related meta questions about questions and provided answers to questions I've seen problems in and the response seems to be 'its not a problem' or 'site shouldn't be used this/that way' where there is no real solution. I also believe there isn't/won't be a great solution and meta seems to be a place to just vent when its about questions/users

BTW, is there any more to Mark's saga posted here on Meta? I just this week saw that his username is gone. Or was it just a temporary username someone was using to post a list of though-provoking (and sometimes just plain provoking) questions?

@Conrado  Interesting. My personal notes on users have a question-mark as to whether Mark used to have an older a/c that had been removed. There's nothing to stop a 'removed' account-holder from setting up a new account and carrying on where they'd been forced (or chose) to leave off. I note certain recurring question-types, and phrases. Not proof of anything, of course, but I just happen to sometimes notice, and wonder.

On many of the sites within the Stack Exchange platform there is an encouragement to those who would down-vote an answer to leave a comment in explanation so that the contributor may be able to, perhaps, edit their question or, alternatively, learn by experience what questions are best for the site.
And the opposite is also relevant in that if a question is up-voted, a comment may be left as to the reason for the approval.
This is not 'hiring mercenaries' as you put it. It is simply an appreciation and encouragement to a contributor, most especially in conditions where, due to perhaps a controversial situation, the contributor is receiving adverse comment and down-vote from other users.
This is how the platform operates, on approval and disapproval.
There is no 'mercenary' background at play.

The Moderator system, of elected Moderators from within the user Community, enables any user, if they find fault with a comment, to flag that comment for Moderator consideration.
It is a very effective means of moderation.
For one user to prevail upon another to delete comments they have made, is a form of unauthorised censorship. Much better is it, to flag for an elected Moderator to make a decision.

As an aside, I agree that users should not be calling down curses on one another. Although it may be true that persons holding untruths may rightly be what Paul calls 'accursed' it is definitely not proper for users on this site to apply such words to fellow users. In that, I agree.

I've never quite understood the assumption that you have to give a constructive comment on a downvote, but you should do upvotes without saying what you like about the post.  I'm of the opinion that criticism can be both positive and negative. That being said, comments are primarily for clarification from the OP.  It might be better to pass over the more controversial posts.

I think that is a well-balanced perspective @PeterTurner.

related: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/22319 I'd hope the approval/disapproval is on the content or quality of a post not necessarily that it supports one's opinion though.

@depperm One will have an opinion about the content and the quality and one will vote according to that opinion. 'Quality' is a matter of opinion.

@NigelJ I've voted for posts that I don't agree with, when I find the post asks a good question or answers a question even if I disagree with the contents. Yes it is a matter of opinion, but users can refrain from voting purely for/against content that aligns with one's beliefs.
